# Cycles Shader Nodes - Where/How to learn advanced and clever nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shader-nodes

Where/How do I approach moving from an intermediate to advanced Cycles Shader node user?  I recently came across a youtube landscape tutorial that shows how to mask off displacement of peaks with just one part shown in image.  While I understand what each of these nodes does by itself and to some extent together, I am totally lost when it comes the general workflow and desired results and unfortunately, many youtube videos show what to do but don't really explain why or how.  Please note, I am NOT looking specifically for an explanation of this node setup, although one might be helpful.  I AM LOOKING for where to go to learn/understand the language of these nodes so that I can use them for whatever purpose I might need them for on any project.  I have questions like:

1. Why does he know to start with a CombineXYZ with specific values?
2. Why is that Averaged (Add/Normalize) with the Normal?  What does that do?
3. Why is the image texture multiplied and then subtracted and then multiplied with the ColorRamp?  What does that do?
4. How do I know when a sequence of Math nodes is useful or needed as this author seemed to know?

Yes, I have NodeWrangler and I am familiar with Ctrl-Shft click to visualize the current node, but that is not an explanation, it's just feedback of varying usefulness.

I've recently seen node setups that seem to use multiple math nodes in sequence - are they setups following well known GC formulae/algorithms that people already know?  The only time I ever use a Math node on my own is when I need to multiply or divide an effect like displacement because it is too large or too small.  But in videos I see people using multiple math nodes or Mix Node Multiply quite a bit but I've not found good explanations as to why or how they know they need to use them.

It's like a dictionary or recipe book of shader nodes would be useful.

I know this is a not a great specific question but I have to ask. This is preventing me (I think) from moving from beginner/intermediate to intermediate/advanced shader creator.

[image]

Youtube videos are a great way to get up and running with blender but I've not found any good resource on how to internalize the language of shader nodes (and for that matter GNs other than for creating great particle systems).  I've also not found the blender manual helpful here either.

There must be some resources somewhere that can help me get over this hump.  Finally, I did recently find some resources that helped me build this interesting (not sure if overly useful yet) setup that produced this output.  ***Ultimately I am a hobbyist who would like to be able to create a very realistic looking landscapes that are well shaded for height and slope, with snowy peaks, cliffs and levels of vegetation and water etc AND understand exactly what I am doing and why w/o buying projects or assets.***

[image]